# Problema em programa "criptografador" de textos em Java

Tags: java, criptografia

Então pessoal, estou com um probleminha em um dos exercícios do trabalho que tenho que fazer.

A professora forneceu um `.doc` com as instruções para um "**Programa Criptografador**" que deve aplicar uma máscara no alfabeto e criptografar um texto (estilo Enigma). Veja o enunciado do exercício:

Seu programa deverá ter um método para criptografar e descriptografar um documento.

Em ambos métodos, o arquivo de texto deverá ser carregado e a chave (valor inteiro de 2 a 5) solicitada ao usuário.

Vamos imaginar que cada letra possui um valor inteiro. Iniciamos com a letra `A`, que possui valor `0`. Em seguida `B` com valor `1`, `C` com o valor `2` e assim por diante até a letra `Z`.

Veja a tabela abaixo:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25
```

Ao criptografarmos um documento faremos o seguinte:

Convertemos a letra que queremos criptografar, colocando em seu lugar e letra que se encontra na sua posição + chave.

Por exemplo:

Queremos converter a letra `B`. Vamos supor que a chave inserida pelo usuário seja `3`.

`B` se encontra na posição `1`. A posição de `B` + a chave resulta em `4`. Logo, substituiremos a letra `B`, pela letra `E`.

Se a palavra for `BANANA`, usando a chave `3`, ela será convertida para `EDQDQD`.

Caso o valor obtido pela soma da posição e da chave seja maior que 25 (letra Z), então deverá continuar no começo do alfabeto.

Por exemplo: 
Queremos converter a letra `X`. Vamos supor que a chave inserida pelo usuário seja `5`.

`X` se encontra na posição `23`. A posição de `X` + a chave resulta em `28`. Se voltarmos ao começo do alfabeto, o número `28` cairá na letra `C`. Logo, substituiremos a letra `X`, pela letra `C`.

Se a palavra for `XUXU`, usando a chave `5`, ela será convertida para `CZCZ`.
Além disso espaços em branco devem ser convertido para um sustenido (#).
Ao descriptografarmos, faremos o processo inverso."

Já fiz boa parte do código, mas alguns problemas surgem: no texto de saída, ao invés de aparecer "`#`" ele quebra uma linha entre as palavras.

Caso tenham alguma dúvida em relação a clareza da minha explicação do problema, favor comentar.

Segue o código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class trab3{

public static void main(String [] args){
    inicio();
}

public static void inicio(){
    try{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println("\finforme o nomedoarquivo.txt:");
        String arquivo = in.nextLine();
// o arquivo de entrada deve estar previamente colocado na pasta do projeto

        File arquivoDeEntrada = new File(arquivo);
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(arquivoDeEntrada); 

        System.out.println("informe o nomedoarquivodesaida.txt:");
        String arquivosaida = in.nextLine();
// para selecionar o nome do arquivo de saida

        PrintWriter saida = new PrintWriter(arquivosaida); 

        int op = 0;
        int chave;
        do{
            System.out.println("Digite 1 para criptografar o arquivo");
            System.out.println("Digite 2 para descriptografar o arquivo");
            op = in.nextInt();
            if(op != 1 && op != 2){
                System.out.println("Opção inválida.");
                inicio();
            } else {
                System.out.println("informe a chave de 1 até 5");
                chave = in.nextInt();
                if(chave != 1 && chave != 2 && chave != 3 && chave != 4 && chave != 5){
                System.out.println("Chave inválida");
                inicio();
                }
                leituraEscritaDosArquivos(entrada, saida, op, chave);
            }
        } while (op != 1 && op != 2);            
    } catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Erro com o arquivo. Tente novamente");
        inicio();
    }
} 

public static void leituraEscritaDosArquivos(Scanner entrada,  PrintWriter saida, int op, int chave){

    while(entrada.hasNext()){  
        String palavra = entrada.next().toUpperCase();

        String resultado = "";
        int key = chave;
        if(op == 1){
            resultado = criptografa(palavra, key);
        }
        else{
            resultado = descriptografa(palavra, key);
        }

        saida.println(resultado);

    }
    saida.close();
    entrada.close();
    System.out.println("Saída gerada com sucesso.");
}

public static String criptografa(String palavra, int chave){    
    String alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String resultado = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < palavra.length(); i++){
        if(palavra.indexOf(palavra.charAt(i)) == ' '){
            char novaletra = '#';
            resultado = resultado + novaletra;
        }else{
            int posicaodaletra = alfabeto.indexOf(palavra.charAt(i));
            int novaposicao = posicaodaletra + chave;
            if(novaposicao > 25){
                char novaletra = alfabeto.charAt(posicaodaletra+chave-26);
                resultado = resultado + novaletra;
            }else{
                char novaletra = alfabeto.charAt(novaposicao);
                resultado = resultado + novaletra;
            }

        }
    }
    return resultado;
}

public static String descriptografa(String palavra , int chave){    
    String alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String resultado = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < palavra.length(); i++){
        if(palavra.indexOf(palavra.charAt(i)) == ' '){
            char novaletra = '#';
            resultado = resultado + novaletra;
        }else{
            int posicaodaletra = alfabeto.indexOf(palavra.charAt(i));
            int novaposicao = posicaodaletra - chave;
            if(novaposicao < 0){
                char novaletra = alfabeto.charAt(posicaodaletra-chave+26);
                resultado = resultado + novaletra;
            }else{
                char novaletra = alfabeto.charAt(novaposicao);
                resultado = resultado + novaletra;
            }

        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
}
```

Comment: Veja se o problema está na hora de salvar o arquivo ou na criptografia dele, faça com que apareça no console antes de salvar e veja onde está problema.

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema é que você está usando o `Scanner` para ler o arquivo, e não um simples `BufferedReader` ou similar. O `Scanner` quebra a entrada em palavras, de modo que:

1. Nunca aparecerá um espaço em branco, pois o `Scanner` não os retorna (ao encontrar um, ele devolve a palavra que ele acabou de ler, e ao chamar `next` ele inicia a leitura de uma nova palavra);
2. Você está fazendo um `println` após converter cada palavra, o que introduz uma quebra de linha entra elas.

Ao fazer qualquer conversão reversível do conteúdo de arquivos, é importante preservar toda informação, de modo que não recomendo o uso de `Scanner`. Sugiro substituir:

```
File arquivoDeEntrada = new File(arquivo);
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(arquivoDeEntrada);
```

por:

```
File arquivoDeEntrada = new File(arquivo);
BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivo));
```

(Nota: nesse caso pode, pois o arquivo é ASCII - na prática, levar também em consideração a codificação de caracteres - *encoding* - do arquivo)

E, embora não seja o ideal (para fins desse exercício creio estar ok), substituir a leitura de várias "palavras" pela leitura de linhas inteiras do arquivo:

```
while(entrada.hasNext()){  
    String palavra = entrada.next().toUpperCase();
    ...
    saida.println(resultado);
}
```

por

```
for ( String linha = entrada.readLine() ; linha != null ; linha = entrada.readLine() ) {
    palavra = linha.toUpperCase();
    ...
    saida.println(resultado);
}
```

Isso resolve seu problema das quebras de linha. Detalhe: não sei se foi erro na hora de transcrever, mas quando você verifica por "chave inválida" as chaves do `if` estão fechando no lugar errado:

```
if(chave != 1 && chave != 2 && chave != 3 && chave != 4 && chave != 5){
System.out.println("Chave inválida");
inicio(); // chama inicio() se a chave for inválida?!
}         // e NÃO CHAMA se a chave for válida?!!!
leituraEscritaDosArquivos(entrada, saida, op, chave);
```

Procure sempre **identar** seu código corretamente, isso facilita perceber erros desse tipo.

### Comentários

1. Por que você testa por todos os valores de `1` a `5` para a chave? Não seria mais simples fazer:

   ```
   if ( chave < 1 || 5 < chave ){
       System.out.println("Chave inválida");
   ```
2. Esse algoritmo ([Cifra de César](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_C%C3%A9sar)) faz basicamente a soma/subtração módulo 26. O "módulo", como você deve ter estudado em matemática, é basicamente o resto da divisão, que em Java pode ser feito através do operador `%`:

   ```
   int resto = 12 % 5; // 2
   ```

   Tem um detalhe chato que são os números negativos ([Java escolheu fazer com que o sinal do resultado fosse o mesmo sinal do dividendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4403556/520779)). Para contornar isso, é só acrescentar `26` ao fazer a subtração, assim garante-se que o resultado sempre será positivo:

   ```
   // criprografa
   int novaposicao = (posicaodaletra + chave) % 26;

   // descriptografa
   int novaposicao = (posicaodaletra - chave + 26) % 26;
   ```

   O resultado será garantidamente (assumindo que a letra lida não seja inválida, tipo um `Ç`) um número entre `0` e `25`, eliminando a necessidade daquele `if`.
3. Na prática, múltiplas concatenações de string podem causar problemas de desempenho, pois uma nova string é criada a cada operação (já que as strings são imutáveis). Para esse exercício creio não ser necessário, mas acostume-se a usar um `StringBuilder` sempre que precisar fazer várias operações sucessivas com string:

   ```
   // Em vez de:
   String s = "";
   s += str1;
   s += str2;
   s += str3;

   // Faça:
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
   sb.append(str1);
   sb.append(str2);
   sb.append(str3);
   String s = sb.toString();
   ```
4. Apenas por curiosidade, no caso das letras de `A` a `Z` você não precisa de uma string `alfabeto` para converter de/para números de `0` a `25`. Essas letras estão representadas no ASCII (e Unicode/UTF-16) em posições contíguas, onde o `A` é o `65` (hexa `41`) e o `Z` é o `90` (hexa `5A`). Assim, com simples operações numéricas e de *cast* você pode fazer essa conversão sem a necessidade de um *look-up*:

   ```
   char letra = 'B';
   int chave = 3;

   int posLetra = (int)letra;                // 66
   int codLetra = posLetra - 0x41;           // 1
   int convertida = (codLetra + chave) % 26; // 4
   int posConvertida = convertida + 0x41;    // 69
   char letraFinal = (char)posConvertida;    // 'E'
   ```

   Se isso estiver muito confuso pra você, ignore, a clareza do código a princípio é mais importante.